# Transform:translate positioning wrong Internet Exploerer

Tags: css-position, transform, pseudo-element, translate-animation

I am using a number of Pseudo elements throughout a website I am building. They all look great except in IE. I am testing it in IE 10 and 11 to start off with.

For some reason the positioning is always slightly off - in the example below, about 5 px for each element.

I have tried changing the display and positions, setting the origins, but nothing seems to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
.home .welcome-row h1 {
position: relative;
margin-bottom: 0;
}

.home .welcome-row  h1:before {
background-image: url('/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/welcome-line-1.png');
-webkit-transform: translateY(-23px);
-moz-transform: translateY(-23px);
-o-transform: translateY(-23px);
transform: translateY(-23px);
background-size: 260px 13px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 260px;
height: 13px;
content:"";
position: absolute;
display: block;
}

.home .welcome-row  h1:after {
background-image: url('wp-content/uploads/2017/10/welcome-line-2.png');
-webkit-transform: translateY(5px);
-moz-transform: translateY(5px);
-o-transform: translateY(5px);
transform: translateY(5px);
background-size: 260px 13px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 260px;
height: 13px;
content:"";
position: absolute;
display: block;
}
```

*EDIT - I have added any additional theme styles that are applied incase they have any relevance.

```
*:after,
*:before {
box-sizing:border-box
}

:-webkit-any(article,aside,nav,section) h1 {
    -webkit-margin-before: 0.83em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 0.83em;
}

user agent stylesheet
    h1 {
        -webkit-margin-before: 0.67em;
        -webkit-margin-after: 0.67em;
        -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
        -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
    }

 h1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you use some kind of reset CSS or alter properties of any element outside of the provided CSS snippet? https://jsfiddle.net/stby04/1a56mwar/3/ is only your provided CSS with some lines to see the alignment, and it renders identical in FF, Opera, IE11, IE10 and Edge. The "calculated" tab in the DOM Explorer of IE really helps in cases like this.

Comment: Hi there, I am using a Wordress theme so there is more CSS that I have not included, however I did go through and uncheck/check every other property in the inspector and none made a difference. There was very little and nothing there that I could see that would have any effect.

Comment: I have added any extra CSS I can see

Comment: The -webkit prefix is only understood by Browsers that use Webkit as rendering engine, most notably probably Chrome, but also Opera, Vivaldi or Safari.

Comment: So if the :-webkit-any selector has been defined by you (or WordPress), you will need to either remove it or add a non-prefixed version of it.
The "user agent stylesheet" is a set of CSS rules that are automatically applied by every browser, and they can differ. Search for "Normalize.css" or "Reset.css" to get a set of CSS rules that override and normalize the user agent stylesheets across browsers.